# how to create an android project programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, project

I'm working on an eclipse plugin that needs to offer the option of creating a new Android Project from a given apk. 
I basically want to use the information from the AndroidManifest.xml in the apk to do the project setup.

Basically the steps I want to follow are:

1. unpack the apk using [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)
2. create Android project using some information from the unpacked apk.

I have done this successfully doing both steps manually (as idicated in http://codebangers.com/?p=584)

However, now I'd like to automate the process and do it programmatically. 
I was able to do step 1. programmatically.

Regarding step 2. I know the eclipse ADT plugin provides a NewProjectCreator class, however it seems I should not use this class to create the project since the class helps says:

```
  /**
   * The actual project creator invoked from the New Project Wizard
   * <p/>
   * Note: this class is public so that it can be accessed from unit tests.
   * It is however an internal class. Its API may change without notice.
   * It should semantically be considered as a private final class.
   */
```

Does anybody know what is the correct way of programmatically creating an Android project?

Comment: What possible legal reason is there to do this?

Comment: We would like to do some analysis (related to security) of apks. Setting the project as an Android Project could give us some advantages, like setting the proper android.jar version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is possible for security seasons, however you could change the extension of the apk towards a zip file. If you open the zip file you could see the application code/resources

Comment: Thanks Greezer. Actually, the apktool does the unzipping and I can see files and resources. I just need to know how to create an android project using some information from those resources.